# Clear css style from a select for disable

Tags: html, css

so, I have a page which uses a css stylesheet which unfortunately, I can't modify, This contains:

```
select {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: 1px solid #A9B8C2;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

In the same page, I have a

```
<select id='myid' style='width:400px;'>
```

which is disabled (I tried both disabled in HTML with `disabled` or JS' `element.disabled = true` with the same result).

The problem is that the select due to the CSS inherited does not look disabled at all (even if it is infact disabled).

How can I best clear the CSS style inherited so that my select, once disabled looks like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_disabled)? I do not necessarily want to drop the current style, apart from the unwanted side-effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so, I have a page which uses a css stylesheet which unfortunately, I
>   can't modify

If you can't modify the stylesheet that sets this:

```
select {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #A9B8C2;
}
```

It's *impossible* to revert the `<select>` back to the native version.

---

> The problem is that the select due to the CSS inherited does not look
>   disabled at all (even if it is infact disabled).

In that case, I think you should do this:

```
select[disabled] {
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* whatever you want a disabled select to look like */
}
```

Comment: No problem. I just added a suggestion to my answer that might help you.

Comment: Actually, this worked just the way I wanted! <style type="text/css">
select[disabled] {
    color: graytext;
}
</style>

Comment: Looks like I was being a bit too picky in my initial answer. It is true that you can't get the *exact native look* back (especially between different browsers/operating systems), but that wasn't what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-define some CSS in a script block in your HTML to override the css style along these lines:

```
<html>
 ...your existing file
<script type="text/css">
....my new styles to override the ones I can't change
</script>
</html>
```

Whilst this isn't ideal, it would likely get around this particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

`<SELECT>` doesn't accept CSS styling like other tags because it is rendered by the operating system, not HTML. That's why it looks different on a MAC/PC etc.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. My select changes its appearance due to the CSS code I posted above. If I remove the code from the CSS stylesheet I get what I want (i.e. normal disabled look in case I disable it) -- point is, I can't touch the stylesheet.

Comment: You will discover there are cross-browser and cross-platform issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the color and background color explicitly inline something like below:

```
    <select id='myid' style='width:400px; backgound-color: ####'>
```

Hope this helps!!